# BroadcastReceiver when both Power and Volume buttons are pressed simultaneously

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am new in `Android`, I am wondering if there's any way to capture the simultaneous pressing of both `Volume up` and `Power Button`.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @VasilyKabunov Negative.